# How to access objects in code from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am new to WPF and am trying to understand how to use data binding to bind the controls on my window to objects in my code behind. I see several questions about accessing XAML objects from the codebehind, but that's not what I'm looking for. I already know how to do that.

```
label1.Content = LabelText;
listbox1.ItemsSource = ListItems;
```

I have also seen answers about how to access a class in the codebehind from XAML.

```
<local:MyClass x:Key="myClass" />
```

But I don't see how to apply that to a specific instance of the class. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. The 'Bindings' are obviously incorrect. That is what I need help with.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _labelText;
    private List<string> _listItems = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _labelText = "Binding";
        _listItems.Add("To");
        _listItems.Add("An");
        _listItems.Add("Object");
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return _labelText; }
        set { _labelText = value; }
    }

    public List<string> ListItems
    {
        get { return _listItems; }
        set { _listItems = value; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="SO_Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SO Demo" Height="160" Width="225">
  <Grid DataContext="MainWindow">
    <Label x:Name="label1" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="12,12,0,0" 
           Content="{Binding Path=LabelText}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Width="100" Height="60" Margin="12,44,0,0" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}" DisplayMemberPath="ListItems"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The books and tutorials I have read make it sound like this should be very simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can `DataBind` directly to the class in the manner you're attempting, it is not how this is commonly done.  The recommended approach is to create an object (ViewModel) that aggregates all the model data you want displayed in your UI, and then set that ViewModel as the `DataContext` of your View (Window in this case).  I would recommend reading about MVVM, which is how most WPF application are built.  But the example below can get you started.

Here is a simple example based on your sample above:

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items;

    public string LabelText
    { 
        get { return _title; } 
        set 
        { 
            _title = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems { 
        get { return _items; }
        set 
        { 
            _items = value;   //Not the best way to populate your "items", but this is just for demonstration purposes.
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListItems");
        }
    }

    //Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        //Initialize view model with data...

        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

**View (Window)**

```
<Window x:Class="SO_Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SO Demo" Height="160" Width="225">
  <Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="12,12,0,0"               Content="{Binding Path=LabelText}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Width="100" Height="60" Margin="12,44,0,0" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This helps a lot! I think I remember reading somewhere that the source property (and target?) must be dependency properties. Is that true? Thanks!

Comment: Almost - you've got it backwards.  The Source property can be any public property.  The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used so that updates to the source will automatically be reflected in the target.  The Target does need to be a `DependencyProperty`.  [This MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#creating_a_binding) describes `DataBinding` in great detail and goes into specifics on the Source and the Target.

Answer (score 3):

`<Grid DataContext="MainWindow">` is invalid.

If you want to reference the window you must either:

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow">
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}"/>
</Window>
```

or

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: And the `DisplayMemberPath="ListItems"` should be removed from the ListBox. It's pointless.

Comment: And the properties will need `INotifyPropertyChanged` semantics.

Comment: Ok, then `ListItems` may also be an `ObservableCollection<string>` (or at least implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`) :-)

Comment: Re: "If you want to reference the window you must either: ..."   I just assumed that since LabelText and ListItems were members of my MainWindow class, that I needed to do something like that. Will "<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}"/>" let me access these members?

Comment: @JNygren don't think of UI elements as "members". The Visual tree is precisely that (a tree), therefore it has "nodes", not "members". the `ElementName=MyWindow` in the binding is referencing to the `x:Name="MyWindow"` attribute defined in XAML. It doesn't know about class or member names.